# To prevent scrolling of Spite animation along with the background in openGL ES

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, sprite, game-engine

After using the endless road algorithm as described here, I also implemented the scrolling of walls along with it.
I have the walk animation of the person which is stationed at the center of the screen.

What I did: Background scrolling is implemented according to the endless road algorithm

What's the problem?
The Image of the man is also scrolling like that of the endless road.

What I want: The animation of the person should not scroll but the background should scroll.

I tried along playing with the matrices in openglES using the method... 
"gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE)" but the resultant was that the background scrolling stopped but animation was successful.

I know I am wrong somewhere but I am not able to find my mistake.

Here's my code:

```
public class GLSquare {

FloatBuffer fVertexBuffer, mTextureBuffer;
ByteBuffer mColorBuff;
ByteBuffer mIndexBuff;
int[] textures = new int[1];
public boolean useMipMapping = true;
float _numTextures = 2;
float  incrementTex;
private float _acceleration;
long startTime;
float vertices [] = {
        -2.0f,2.0f,0.0f,            //byte index 0
         2.0f, 2.0f,0.0f,           //byte index 1
         -2.0f, -2.0f,0.0f,         //byte index 2
         2.0f,-2.0f,0.0f,           //byte index 3

    };                  

    float textureCoord[] = {

            0.0f,incrementTex,
            1.0f,incrementTex,
            0.0f,_numTextures+incrementTex,
            1.0f,_numTextures+incrementTex

    };


byte indices[] = {0, 1, 2,
        1, 2, 3 };


public GLSquare() {

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub     
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4); // 4 vertices, 3 co-ordinates(x,y and z) 4 for converting in float
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    fVertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    fVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    fVertexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoord.length * 4);
    byteBuffer2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mTextureBuffer =  byteBuffer2.asFloatBuffer();
    Log.i("texture", "tex corrrrd " + String.valueOf(textureCoord));
    mTextureBuffer.put(textureCoord);
    mTextureBuffer.position(0);

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void draw(GL10 gl){
    gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CW);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3,GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, fVertexBuffer);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    /** for the repetition of road.*/ 
_acceleration += -0.005f * (float)System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;            
    _acceleration = Math.max(_acceleration, 0.002f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
    gl.glTranslatef(0, _acceleration, 0);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    incrementTex -= _acceleration;

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]); //4
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, mTextureBuffer); //5
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); //7

    gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CCW);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);


}

public void createSquareTexture(GL10 gl, Context context, int resource)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resource);
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);


    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_REPEAT, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    bitmap.recycle();   
}

  }
```

And here are methods that are used in the render class...

```
 TextureRegion keyFrame;
public void present(float deltaTime) {

    GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();

    gl.glClearColor(0f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    loadTheWalls(gl);

    guiCamera.setViewportAndMatrices();

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    batcher.beginBatch(texture);
            keyFrame = straightWalk.getKeyFrame(stickMan.straightWalkTime, Animation.ANIMATION_LOOPING);
      drawTheManMethod();
    batcher.endBatch();

}

public void loadTheWalls(GL10 gl){
    /** 
     * 
     * Code for the back scrolling of roads and walls
     * Three squares are taken and the textures are repeated on the respective square.
     * Only two textures are taken here, One for the wall and other for the road.
     * Wall textures are rotated accordingly ap per usage.
     * 
     * */       
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 67, glGraphics.getWidth()
                    / (float) glGraphics.getHeight(), 1f, 100f);

            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);


    /**Square used as a road*/
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glLoadIdentity();
      gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, -1.0f, -4.0f); // Translate to wallpos and into the screen ( NEW )
      gl.glRotatef(-80, 1, 0, 0);
      mSquare2.draw(gl);                   // Draw Square ( NEW )
      gl.glPopMatrix();


      /**Square used as a left wall*/
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glLoadIdentity();
      gl.glTranslatef(-2.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f); // Translate to wallpos and into the screen ( NEW )
      gl.glRotatef(-90, 0, 1, 0);
      gl.glRotatef(90, 0, 0, 1);
      mSquare3.draw(gl);                   // Draw Square ( NEW )
      gl.glPopMatrix();

      /**Square used as a right wall*/
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glLoadIdentity();
      gl.glTranslatef(1.8f, 0.0f, -4.0f); // Translate to wallpos and into the screen ( NEW )
      gl.glRotatef(-85, 0, 1, 0);
      gl.glRotatef(90, 0, 0, 1);
      mSquare1.draw(gl);                   // Draw Square ( NEW )
      gl.glPopMatrix();

}




public void pause() {

}


public void resume() {
    GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();

    texture = new Texture(((GLGame)game), "twocharacter.png");

    straightWalk = new Animation(0.2f, 
            new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 96, 96, 96),
            new TextureRegion(texture, 96, 96, 96, 96),
            new TextureRegion(texture, 96*2, 96, 96, 96),
            new TextureRegion(texture, 96*3, 96, 96, 96),
            new TextureRegion(texture, 96*4, 96, 96, 96),
            new TextureRegion(texture, 96*5, 96, 96, 96),
            new TextureRegion(texture, 96*6, 96, 96, 96),
            new TextureRegion(texture, 96*7, 96, 96, 96)
                );


    int resId2 = R.drawable.buildngs;
      mSquare1.createSquareTexture(gl, getBaseContext(), resId2);

      int resId3 = R.drawable.buildngs;
      mSquare3.createSquareTexture(gl, getBaseContext(), resId3);

      int resId4 = R.drawable.path;
      mSquare2.createSquareTexture(gl, getApplication(), resId4);
}
```

Here are the images for a better understanding.
[image: Part One]
[image: Part Two]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a field in GLSquare called texturePos.

```
private float texturePos = 0.0f;
```

Replace your acceleration section with this:

```
/** for the repetition of road.*/ 
_acceleration += -0.005f * (float)System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;            
_acceleration = Math.max(_acceleration, 0.002f);
texturePos += acceleration;
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glTranslatef(0, texturePos, 0);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
incrementTex -= _acceleration;
```

Notice we push the current matrix onto the stack before translating by texturePos instead of _acceleration and also texturePos is incremented by _acceleration.

Then at the end of your draw method add the following:

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
gl.glPopMatrix();
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
```

So we pop the old texture matrix back off the stack so it's back to normal.

---

Alternatively you could also just call

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

Before drawing your man, but the first method is better because it will work in more situations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kane. This really helped me out clearing the basics.